# Why Parts_Autoroute_Edit template should be rendered for urls to be regenerated?

Tags: orchardcms

If I write:

```
<Place Parts_Autoroute_Edit="-"/>
```

Then code in AutoroutePartDriver

```
 // reset the alias if we need to force regeneration, and the user didn't provide a custom one
 if(settings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit && previous == part.DisplayAlias) {
        part.DisplayAlias = string.Empty;
 }
```

is not executed and pathes don't regenerate.

Could it be worked around? I don't want to display "Permalink" and "Set as home page" func.

Comment: Could you try an alternate instead of removing the template?  Just keep those fields hidden in your alternate.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, that could work but I wondered if that is right or not. I mean if I add autoroute part to my type and set it up to regenerate path on update why I need to render it.